# MySQL count in "complex" SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query: Let me describe it to you quickly. I wanna develop a soccer tip game. I have 4 tables: apps, tips, users, games.

Relations:

```
apps 1 to N users
user 1 to N tips
game 1 to 1 tip
```

Instead of listing all games where the User had a successful tip, I just want to list the u.userId with the COUNT of successful tips. Check out my SQL:

```
SELECT 
    t.*, u.*, g.*
FROM 
    tips AS t,
    users AS u, 
    games AS g
WHERE 
    u.userAppId = 4 AND
    t.tipUserId = u.userId AND
    g.gameResult = t.tipGameResult
```

I guess I somehow have to implement a COUNT and u.userId instead of

```
 t.*, u.*, g.*
```

but I am not 100% sure how to do it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: just change t.*, u.*, g.* to count(*) and this will ount the number of rows answer would have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
u.userid, count(*)
FROM 
tips AS t,
users AS u, 
games AS g
WHERE 
u.userAppId = 4 AND
t.tipUserId = u.userId AND
g.gameResult = t.tipGameResult
group by u.userid
```

As mentioned in comment below, the group by on user id will give you

userid|count(*)

Comment: A `GROUP BY u.userId` will  be needed to correctly apply the aggregate

Comment: :D So damn easy. Thanks!